# On AWS, how do I give access to my subcontractor to create and manage his resources only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am about to start a cooperation with a 3rd party (subcontractor). He wants me to provide him with a development environment (cloud infrastructure). Later on similar infrastructure will be needed for a production environment.

I would like to give the subcontractor full access to EC2 instances that he creates and no access to others. Furthermore he will probably need access to some other services like Elastic Container Services (ECS).

Right now I have a full AWS account with User accounts for my developers.

Is it possible to create a policy for my subcontractor so that he could freely create and manage EC2 instances, but only those which he created? Similarly for ECS?

One other option that I see is to create an entirely new AWS account and create a sub-account for my subcontractor with admin privileges. This way I could separate his work from my own.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest a slightly non technical solution - but would be very easy to get started and make it Production in no time. Please create a new AWS account and you can add that account's billing / invoices to your existing account.

This way you would get a single bill (no worries of multiple payment methods) - the ownership, control & authority can be delegated by creating an IAM user with admin permission; and still you get to have the visibility and cost information about the Sub-Contractor's Account. You can optionally allow your sub-contractor to get access to your billing information.

You can make use of the 2nd AWS Account's root account access to get entry into Sub-Contractors' activities or create an yet another Admin IAM account in that account (recommended approach).

You will make use of Linked Account, Consolidated billing concepts.

**Sources :**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html

https://support.cloudability.com/hc/en-us/articles/200311923-How-to-Set-Up-Consolidated-Billing-at-AWS

[image: Paying Account - Linked Account]

**PS** :

The technical or more complex approach would be create Resource Group(s) - IAM users which in my opinion that is hard to manage and orchestrate. For more info - please check out - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/obtaining-permissions-for-resource-groups.html

Answer (score -1):

You can create IAM accounts and can assign policies to them for this you can follow below steps.

This link will help you more

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-control-aws-resource-using-iam-mansoor-ul-hasan?published=t

Regards,
-Mansur